Can't Find Shrines BoTW
So, I'm working on 100%ing BoTW. I got most of the shrines, and it's hard for me to find more. Is there any secret way to find them that I don't know about or should I just run around with the shieka sensor and hope to find the rest?

Related, possibly dup: "Undetectable" and non-Quest Shrines

Your Hand Held Computer has an option to find shrines near you, it will beep.  Or the official strategy guide has location of every one, or can try googling hard to find ones.

@Brad "I just run around with the shieka sensor and hope to find the rest", OP already knows that

My recommendation is to refer to a map of shrine locations and compare it to your own in-game map to see which shrines you are missing. See the map below from Polygon's shrine guide. (Shines from The Champion's Ballad DLC are marked in green)

